# Select2 de bootstrapp no me muestra los valores de las opciones

Tags: mysql, jquery, bootstrap, select2

Tengo un par de combobox que se alimentan segun la información que les pase, pero en el segundo combobox que tiene la propiedad de select2 no me muestra los valores.

Tengo esta imagen que es como se visualiza los combobox
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Curiosamente al ver que pasa en el inspector de elemento, si funciona, los valores ahi están, pero por alguna razón no me los enseña en este segundo combobox.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código PHP que muestra los valores

```
<?php
include ("../../../config/config.php");


function getMuni(){
    $con = conectar();
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "";
    switch($id){
        case 'artista':
            $query = "SELECT id_artista AS id, nombre_artista AS nombre FROM ARTISTA";
            break;
        case 'categoria':
            $query = "SELECT id_categoria AS id, nombre_categoria AS nombre FROM CATEGORIA";
            break;
        case 'coleccion':
            $query = "SELECT id_coleccion AS id, nombre_coleccion AS nombre FROM COLECCIONES";
            break;
    }
    $result = $con->query($query);
    $selecciones = '<option selected value=0>-- Seleccionar --</option>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $selecciones .= "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[nombre]</option>";
    }
    return $selecciones;
}

echo getMuni();
?>
```

Y esque es el query que contiene el ajax cada vez que haga el cambio.

```
$('#cbx_opciones').on('change', function(){
    var id = $('#cbx_opciones').val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../assets/php/verdatos/cbxinventario.php',
        data: {'id' : id}
    })
    .done(function(getMuni){
        $('#cbx_seleccion').html(getMuni)
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert('Error al cargar municipios');
    })
});
```

A continuación el código HTML de los combobox

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col"><h5>Ver total de obras por:</h5></div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-control" id="cbx_opciones" name="cbx_opciones">
          <option selected>-- Seleccionar --</option>
          <option value="artista">Artista</option>
          <option value="categoria">Categoría</option>
          <option value="coleccion">Colección</option>
          <option value="pais">País</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">             
      <div class="form-group" data-select2-id="47">
        <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" id="cbx_seleccion" name="cbx_seleccion">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Algo también curioso es que si le agrego la propiedad de select2 al otro combobox pasa exactamente lo mismo, no me muestra los valores, unicamente en el inspector de elementos. No sé si alguien le haya encontrado solución a esto. Gracias.

Comment: Lo que es curioso es que no se ve lo que es `#cbx_opciones` en tu código... diría que ahí tienes el fallo, pues entiendo que debería ser  `#cbx_seleccion` en su lugar (ojo, aparece dos veces), pues no entra nunca allí me parece y por eso no sale nada.. Compruébalo y dinos si es eso el problema, y si lo es ya puedes borrar la pregunta, pues sería un fallo tipográfico que dificilmente nadie reproducirá y no ayudará a nadie tampoco.

Comment: Lo que creo es que estás aplicando el select2 al select antes de que cargue la página, la idea es que le coloques el select2 una vez tenga datos.

Comment: @masterguru Una disculpa por responder tarde, ya edité la pregunta con el código HTML de los combobox, no sé si a eso te referías.

Comment: @Dabydat coloqué el código para cargar el select2 `$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();` únicamente cuando empiece a mostrar las opciones pero sigue sin salirme ningun resultado, al momento de quitarlo los resultados ya los muestra, pero sin la opción de búsqueda.

Comment: Si pones esto: `$('.js-example-basic-single').select2();` debajo de la línea del done esta: `$('#cbx_seleccion').html(getMuni)`  no te funciona?  (quita o comenta las otras que tengas iguales por ahi)

Comment: mmm... tampoco creo que sea eso... acabo de hacer [algunas pruebas](https://jsfiddle.net/y0vzbjns/) (sin ajax) y en todos los casos me los agrega bien, haga como lo haga... no se reproducir tu error por lo tanto no puedo ayudarte, lo siento.

Comment: @masterguru Si, hice eso y la información ahí esta al darle inspeccionar elemento pero lo que muestra es el combobox con el formato de select2 pero sin ningun resultado. Igual te agradezco mucho por tu tiempo.

Comment: ¿Y eso te pasa con distintos navegadores?  Es por ir probando y descartando cosas, quizas la cache tenga algo que ver.

Comment: @masterguru Si, ocurre con distintos navegadores, de por si tengo que borre el historial al cerrar el navegador.